# Mostrar texto de un array dinamico

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando una app de siniestros de autos, estoy acumulando los detalles en un array de la siguiente manera

```
const arrayDamages = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const arr = {
            'sectorDamage': e.target.sectorDamages.value,
            'damageDetails': e.target.damageDetails.value,
            'severityCode': e.target.severityCodes.value,
            'damageCode': e.target.damageCodes.value,
        }

        setArrDamage([
            ...arrDamage,
            arr
        ])
    }
```

Los datos se toman y muestran de de la siguiente manera

```
<h2>LISTADO</h2>
        {
            arrDamage.length > 0 ? (
                <>
                    {
                        arrDamage?.map((type, i) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={i}>{type.sectorDamage} / {type.damageDetails} / {type.severityCode} / {type.damageCode} <a href="x">[x]</a></li>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </>
            ) : (<></>)
        }
        <ol>

        </ol><br />

        <hr />

        <form onSubmit={arrayDamages}>
            <p>
                Agregar siniestros
                <label>Sector de daño </label>
                <select name="sectorDamages" onChange={changeSectorDamage}>
                    {
                        sectorDamage?.map(type => {
                            return (
                                <option key={type._id} value={type._id}>{type.name}</option>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </select><br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Detalle </label>
                <select name="damageDetails">
                    {
                        damageDetails?.map(type => {
                            return (
                                <option key={type._id} value={type._id}>{type.code} - {type.details}</option>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </select><br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Codigo de gravedad </label>
                <select name="severityCodes">
                    {
                        severityCode?.map(type => {
                            return (
                                <option key={type._id} value={type._id}>CODIGO: {type.code} - {type.details}</option>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </select><br />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Codigo de daño </label>
                <select name="damageCodes">
                    {
                        damageCode?.map(type => {
                            return (
                                <option key={type._id} value={type._id}>CODIGO: {type.code} - {type.details}</option>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </select><br />
            </p>

            <input type="submit" value='cargar daño' /> <br />
        </form>
```

La idea es guardar unicamente los id de los valores de los select, que eso lo esta haciendo bien, pero quiero mostrarle a los usuarios los valores que va seleccionando pero no me estoy dando cuenta de como mostrarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria almacenar los id y a su vez mostrar los nombres correspondiente a los id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Donde los muestras, tendrías que ir a buscar el Id y ver a que nombre pertenece:

algo como:

```
<li key={i}>{sectorDamage.find(x => x._id === type.sectorDamage)?.name}</li>
```

Y asi similar con los demás datos que quieras mostrar